# How to display number of records in a MySQL Table row which are not empty?

Tags: mysql

I have this table "test" inside my database having 4 columns email,name,name1,name2 respectively.

[image]

Using php I want to display only those records which are not empty for the respective email. So far I come up with this query.

```
<?php
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
 WHERE email = 'muddasir_ist@yahoo.com' 
   AND name != '' 
   AND name1 !='' 
   AND name2 !=''
";
    
$data = mysqli_query($connec,$query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($data);

echo "Total People Are ". $total;
?>
```

Unfortunately it is either showing 0 or the code simply displays nothing as if the query is wrong. I have even tried

```
"AND name1 IS NOT NULL "
```

Is there any way where for the 1st email it show me 3 records for for 2nd email it show only 2?

Comment: Replace unuseful screenshot with according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO textual code-formatted scripts, show desired table-formatted output for this data. PS. Normalize your data stiring structure. And the task solution will be easy.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have all the non null or non empty names in a single column for a desired email address then you can use union as below:

> ```
> create table test(email varchar(50), name varchar(50),name1 varchar(50),name2 varchar(50));
> insert into test values('hassan@gmail.com','Tomek','Michael','Abraham');
> insert into test values('muddasir_ist@yahoo.com','John','','Sarah');
> ```

Query:

> ```
> select email, name from test where email='muddasir_ist@yahoo.com' and name!='' and name is not null
> union all
> select email, name1 from test where email='muddasir_ist@yahoo.com' and name1!='' and name1 is not null
> union all
> select email, name2 from test where email='muddasir_ist@yahoo.com' and name2!='' and name2 is not null
> ```

Output:

> | email | name |
> | --- | --- |
> | muddasir_ist@yahoo.com | John |
> | muddasir_ist@yahoo.com | Sarah |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d71611afce54db46a037f2076ba2207c)*